# SQL Server load balancing optimizing Hits or Optimize the query

Tags: asp.net, .net, ado.net, connection-pooling, scalable

When we developers write data access code what should we really worry about if the application should scale well and handle the load / Hits.

Given this simple problem , how would you solve it in scalable manner.

1.`ProjectResource` is a Class ( Encapsulating resources assigned to a `Project`)

2.Each resource assigned to Project is `User` Class

3.Each `User` in the `Project` also has `ReportingHead` and `ProjectManager` who are also instance of `User`

4.Finally there is a `Project` class containing project details

#### Legend of classes used

- User
- Project
- ProjectResource

#### Table Diagram

1. ProjectResource

   - ResourceId
   - ProjectId
   - UserId
   - ReportingHead
   - ProjectManager

#### Class Diagram

1. ProjectResource

   - ResourceId     : String / Guid
   - Project        : Project
   - User           : User
   - ReportingHead  : User
   - ProjectManager : User

**note:**

All the user information is stored in the User table

All the Project information is stored in the project table

#### Here's the Problem

When the application requests for Resource In a Project operations below are followed

- First Get the Records for the Project
- Get the UserId , make the request(using `Users DAL`) to get the user instance
- Get the ProjectId, make the request(using `Projects DAL`) to get the project information
- Finally assign `Users` and `Project` to instance of `ProjectResource`

clearly you can see `3 Db Calls` are made here for populating single `ProjectResource` but the concerns and who manages the objects are clearly defined. **This is the way i have planned** to , since there is also `connection pooling` available in `Sql Server` & `ADO.net`

There is also another way where all the details are retrieved in single hit using Table Inner Joins and then Populating.

Which way should i really be taking and Why?

#### Extras:

.NET 2.0,ASP.net 2.0,C#,Sql Server 2005,DB on same machine hosting application.

Comment: @someone who wants to close the question do you care to explain why? with all the details put in question does not come to your understanding??

Comment: I can't speak for the person who voted to close, but I can say that your question has more detail than needed to answer what you appear to be asking, which clouds your actual question. For the SO format, it's better to focus on a narrow, programming-related question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For best performance and scalability, you should minimize the number of round-trips to the DB. To prove that to yourself, just run some benchmarks; it becomes clear very quickly.

One approach to a single round-trip is to use joins. Another is to return multiple result sets. The latter can be helpful in eliminating possible duplicate data.

Comment: Then i shall follow the `single Fetch & Populate` way thanks :)